# Passing a dictionary to Vue.js store

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a store in my vue.js product where I want to add dictionaries under this format:

```
 axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${this.endpoint}/`, fd, axiosConfig)
        .then(res => {                       
          let newPictureUrl = res.data.picture_1
          let newPictureId = res.data.id
          let addPicDic = {"url": newPictureUrl, "id": newPictureId}          
          this.addPicture(addPicDic) })
```

This is my store.js:

```
export const store = {
    state: {
      pictures: []
    },
    addPicture(newPicture) {      
      this.state.pictures.push(newPicture);
    }
  };
```

But whenever I want to render my pictures in a template, it doesn't work and `{{ storeState.pictures }}` would return `[ "[object Object]" ]`.
As far as I understand, I get an object 'Object' instead of a 'Dictionary' so how can I pass my datas to the store so I can access them in other templates?

Comment: `"[object Object]"` is a string, and it means you are casting an object to string somewhere. for example `const a = {}; console.log( a.toString() );` would give `"[object Object]"`.  Is localstorage (which can only store strings) involved perhaps?  Also `Dictionary` is not a thing in javascript, you *really do* want an object, but you don't want an object cast to a string.

Comment: Is  ```storeState``` a computed property which mapped to ```this.$root.$store.state``` inside your component.

Comment: to `this.$root.$data` I guess, It works fine if I only pass one argument like: 
`let newPictureUrl = res.data.picture_1
this.addPicture(newPictureUrl)`

Answer (score 0):

So looking at that code, it looks like you are trying to directly modify the store. You should change the state of the store via mutations. In an ideal setup, your component would have a method that would dispatch an action in the store. This asynchronous action would call the endpoint and then commit with a mutation.

```
state: {
  pictures: []
},
mutations: {
  addPicture(state, newPicture) {
    state.pictures.push(newPicture)
  }
}
```

Consult mutations and actions in the [documentation here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html).

Comment: I am not using Vuex in my project, just regular Vue.js

Comment: If you have a "store" without Vuex, I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you're just using the component's local state, you need to return it in a `data` property.

Comment: I was following this doc: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that `store.state.pictures` is an array of objects.

If you want to render all images, you can use `v-for`. It will iterate over the array.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img v-for="pic in storeState.pictures" :key="pic.id" :src="pic.url">
  </div>
</template>
```

**OR**

If you want to display just information (id, urls),

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="pic in storeState.pictures" :key="pic.id" > ID: {{pic.id}} | URL: {{pic.url}} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

I assumed that `storeState` is a computed property which is mapped to the your `store.state`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you console.log ```storeState.pictures```

Comment: I if pass one argument, let say the url, I get a array of urls. If I pass two arguments like in my question I get an array of [ "[object Object]" ]

Comment: It says that the array has two objects (Ex: [ {...}, {...} ] ). Please try console.log it from browser console.

Comment: With two arguments I get :  `["http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/fricoteurs_menus_KoeQZmO.jpg", "[object Object]"` so the first one (the url) is passed correctly but not the second one (the id)

Comment: That is weird! I expected something like, ```storeState.pictures = [ { url: "http//..", id:"id1" }, { url: "http//..", id:"id2"  } ]```. Are you sure about you are using backend API correctly. Is that `res.data.picture_1` and `res.data.id` correct?

Comment: Yes because at first I just passed the URL and rendered them in a view. All my pictures are displayed as it should but now I want to add their id so I can delete them through the API.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I had to change `this.addPicture()` for `store.addPicture()`:

```
axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${this.endpoint}/`, fd, axiosConfig)
        .then(res => {                       
          let newPictureUrl = res.data.picture_1
          let newPictureId = res.data.id
          let addPicDic = {"url": newPictureUrl, "id": newPictureId}          
          store.addPicture(addPicDic) })
```